# PHP multibyte string concat and comparison?

Tags: php, encoding, utf, multibyte, non-ascii-characters

Win7-HUN, UTF8 PHP file.

```
function Test($Msg){

 $Result = "";
 $ReplFrom = "ő";
 $ReplTo = "ö";

 for($i=0; $i<mb_strlen($Msg); $i++){
 $c = mb_substr($Msg, $i, 1);
 echo($c);echo("<br>");
 }
}

Test('őű');
```

This showing good: "őű"

I want to replace "ő" with "ö" but one-by-one, because I want to check many other things.

```
function Test($Msg){

 $Result = "";
 $ReplFrom = "ő";
 $ReplTo = "ö";

 for($i=0; $i<mb_strlen($Msg); $i++){
 $c = mb_substr($Msg, $i, 1);
 $add = $c;
 $h = mb_substr($ReplFrom, 0, 1);
 if ($c == $h) {
 $add = $ReplTo;
 echo("found");
 }
 $Result = $Result.$add;
 }

 return $Result;

}
```

Interesting that is found all chars, and the result is wrong.

Simplified to concat:

```
 $what = 'ő';
 $replto = "ö";
 echo($what.$replto);
```

This is good.

```
 $what = mb_substr('ő', 0, 1);
 $replto = mb_substr("ö", 0, 1);
 echo($what.$replto);
```

This is wrong.

What I do wrong?
I want to step in every MB character, and check it. If some of them needed, I must replace.
If some of them illegal, replace them with " ". Etc.
And at the end concat to one string.

for example:
"álmos ő körben + 2"
"álmos ö körben   2"

But something is wrong in my code.
I want to use UTF8 chars, because I have MultiByte input, and UTF8 or 16 XML.
And some of the servers are english, some of hungarian (encoding is different).

But interesting that something is get wrong when I want to working with MB chars.
Maybe the concatentation causes this?

Very-very thanks for every advance in this theme!

Regards:
  dd

Comment: What exactly is that "something" that does wrong? What's the result?

Comment: Uninterpreateble characters I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to specify encoding for mb_ functions.

```
$c = mb_substr($Msg, $i, 1,'utf-8');
```